# Upload video with facebook api to my page but I getting #100 every time

Tags: facebook-graph-api, video-upload

I'm created a page for testing and I'm trying upload video to this page (page is unpublished) but I'm getting same error every time.

Error: (#100) No permission to publish the video

I created user token on Graph API Explorer with user_videos, publish_video, manage_pages, pages_show_list, publish_pages, publish_to_groups, public_profile permissions.

Anybody know this problem solve?

My code is;

```
const fs = require('fs');
const fbUpload = require('facebook-api-video-upload');

const args = {
  token: "[TOKEN]", // with the permission to upload
  id: "[PAGE_ID]", //The id represent {page_id || user_id || event_id || group_id}
  stream: fs.createReadStream('./content/lake.mp4'), //path to the video,
  title: "video title 1",
  description: "video description 1",
  thumb: {
    value: fs.createReadStream('./content/lake.mp4'),
    options: {
      filename: 'lake.jpg',
      contentType: 'image/jpg'
    }
  }

};

fbUpload(args).then((res) => {
  console.log('res: ', res);

}).catch((e) => {
  console.error(e.message);
});
```

Comment: Did you use a page access token for the request, or just your user token?

Comment: I used both of them. Same response.